# Set image to imageView by ID programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, imageview

I'm developing an iOS app and i have a for loop to create images.
When an image receives the click, i would like to change the background of the image, only to that image. how can I do this?

This is my code:

```
for (int i =0; i<dim; i++) {

likeImageImageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(paddWidth*20,7.5,39.6,39.6)];

    img0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"like"];
    [likeImageImageview setImage:img0];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapImagesLike)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;                                                                                                 
    likeImageImageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;                                                                                            //l'utente può cliccare
    [likeImageImageview setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];                                                                                            //non è consentito il multitouch
    [likeImageImageview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

[row_like addSubview:likeImageImageview];

}
```

And this is the method:

```
-(void)tapImagesLike{               

 likeImageImageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mylike"];

}
```

With this code, only the last `imageview` changes its background. How can I use "i" like an `ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for loop

UIImageView *imageView = …

imageView.tag = i;
```

So you need to get the view that was tapped

```
- (void)tapImagesLike:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)recognizer.view;
    int i = imageView.tag;
    // Then you can do the change you need to do here
}
```

This is the method that should be called when the gesture recognizer tap occurs.

Comment: This also requires you change `@selector(tapImagesLike)` to `@selector(tapImagesLike:)` when creating the gesture.

Comment: ok, now it works but i receive this warning: incompatible pointer types assignign to "UIImageView" from "UIView".
Then, how can i pass the parameter "i" to the method? because i have to use it.

Comment: One solution is to use the tag value of the image view and set it to i's value the second solution would be to use the objective c runtime and associate the value with your image view, the first is the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It only display the last image because your are creating a new instance in a for loop.

Try this

```
NSMutableArray *tempImageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i =0; i<10; i++) {

   UIImageView *likeImageImageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,7.5,39.6,39.6)];

   UIImage *img0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"like"];
    [likeImageImageview setImage:img0];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapImagesLike:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [row_like addSubview:likeImageImageview];
    [tempImageArray addObject:likeImageImageview];
}
self.imageArray=tempImageArray;
[tempImageArray release];
```

And

```
- (void)tapImagesLike:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
     UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:0];
     imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.png"];  
}
```